# How to count every user likes & get top users likes?

Tags: php, laravel, statistics

I am creating statistics for my website and I am trying to get the top 10 users with the most likes. I have two tables (users,users_likes).

The output I want is:

```
------------------------
Username  |  Total Likes
------------------------
user 1    |     25 likes
------------------------
user 2    |     22 likes
------------------------
user 3    |     15 likes
------------------------
```

Comment: Show us the attributes from the users_likes table, please.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this directly through a query, by `join`ing the two tables together, and then `group`ing the results by the username, and getting the `count(*)` of the likes.

One caveat with a `join` is that an inner join will only show you users who actually have likes, so if a user has no likes, they won't be displayed. So instead of a regular inner join, you can do an `outer join` between the users and users_likes table, so that it will always return all of the users, even if they don't have likes. If you `count()` a column from the users_likes results, it will output "0", since null values (as returned by the outer join) will not counted.

Here is an example of how you could do this. This query assumes that you join your users and users_likes table based on a `username` column. This isn't ideal table design, but this should be enough to get you stated, unless you can post your table schemas.

```
select
    users.username, count(users_likes.username) as total_likes
from
    users
    left outer join users_likes
        on (users.username=users_likes.username)
group by
    users.username
order by
    count(users_likes.username) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

1- You have 2 models `User.php` and `UserLike.php`

2- users table PK is `id` and FK in `user_likes` table is `user_id`

3- inside User model you defined hasMany userLikes relation :

```
<?php

//has Many UserLikes
public function userLikes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserLike::class);
}
```

You can achieve it with :

```
<?php

$users = \App\User::withCount('userLikes')
                ->orderBy('user_likes_count', 'desc')
                ->take(10)
                ->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo '<br/>User '.$user->id.' - '.$user->user_likes_count;
}
```